# tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: default value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, return, return-value

I want to have a single custom section header, with the rest being the default header.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     return ???;
}
```

What do I return to just give the default header view?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default header view is `nil`, for no header at all!

Comment: Thanks :) turns out it was crashing because of something else I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the documentation doesn't say how to provide the default view.  Have you tried returning `nil` to see what happens?

If that doesn't work, here's what I would recommend to work around it (this is operating under the assumption that you need to switch between showing the default header and showing a custom header dynamically):

- Add a `BOOL` ivar to the tableview delegate object called `shouldShowDefaultHeader`.
- Override the `respondsToSelector` method to do something like this:

```
if (shouldShowDefaultHeader == YES && [NSStringFromSelector(aSelector) isEqual:@"tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:"]) { return NO; }
return [super respondsToSelector:aSelector];
```

- Toggle the `shouldShowDefaultHeader` ivar accordingly.

Edit: reading the other answers, returning `nil` should work fine instead of mucking around with selectors.  However, it's cool that you can do it anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

As Saeed says, the default return value is "`nil`".

If you want a view in place, you can alloc a custom view within that method and make it return that view.

For example, if you want a picture as the header for that section, you should do something like:

```
[view addSubview:pictureView];

return view;
```

This will return that view for the section whose index you passed in.