# Give the header only to specified table

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, uitableview

I had two UITableView in my project and I am giving custom header to one table using the method:

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(tableView.tag == 3)
    {
    SectionInfo *array  = [self.sectionInfoArray objectAtIndex:section];
    if (!array.sectionView)
    {
        NSString *title = array.groupdeck.groupTitle;
        array.sectionView = [[SectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tblData.bounds.size.width, 45) WithTitle:title Section:section delegate:self];
    }
    return array.sectionView;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }

return 0;
}
```

It is giving the header to the table with the tag 3 like:

[image]

But it is giving the default header to other table also even `return 0` else condition like:

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
otherTable.sectionHeaderHeight = 0.0;
```

You don't have to do anything else.

Or:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
 { 
      if(tableView.tag == 3)
      {
          //Required height.
      }
      else
      {
          return 0.0; 
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

It might be defaulting to the default header because you returned a `0`. Try returning `nil` instead.

From: [tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: default value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552725/tableviewviewforheaderinsection-default-value)

Comment: Hmm... Then you could try setting this:

`- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0.0;
}`

Answer (score 0):

With Reference to written in Apple Documentation

```
 // custom view for header. will be adjusted to default or specified header height
    - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

It is displaying the default header which has **height of 22 for grouped table** and **10 for nongrouped table**.

Also if the height of your view which you want to display in `UITableView`  is more than above values then you also have to use the `UITableView` Delegate method

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```